# Active layer update in ArcIMS?

Tags: javascript, arcims

I'm trying to change the active layer in ArcIMS from the default top position to index 2 in the TOC.  The TOC has 3 grouped layers, but it is the first grouped layer that I want the active layer to be updated to position 2 not the default position 0.  I found this [code link from esri](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/26575) showing how to update the active layer, however I can not seem to figure it out.  Here is the code from the aimsLayers.js file.

```
//ActiveLayerIndex=<number of the preferred active layer>;
    ActiveLayerIndex=1;

    if (ActiveLayerIndex>=layerCount) ActiveLayerIndex = 0;
    if (!LayerIsFeature[ActiveLayerIndex]) {
        var chk = 0;

        for (var i=layerCount-1;i>=0;i--) {
            if (LayerIsFeature[i]) chk = i;
        }
        ActiveLayerIndex = chk;
    }
```

I added the "ActiveLayerIndex=" and changed it to "**ActiveLayerIndex=1;**" the active layer moved one down to position 1 in the TOC.  When I change it to 2 it did not move to position 2 in the TOC and displays no active layer.  When I change the index in this line, **if (ActiveLayerIndex>=layerCount) ActiveLayerIndex = 0;**, it does not update the active layer either.  How can I get the active layer to be on the third layer (position 2) in the TOC?

**UPDATE**

I found another code snippet and was wondering by using it to point to the specific layer name in the TOC if it will re-assign the active layer?  Looks like it could be called within the TOC.htm

```
//global reference to mapframe
    var t = parent.MapFrame;

    function layerName(theFormRef) {
        var theLayerNumber = -1;
        var theLayer = theFormRef.value;

        for (var i=0;i<t.LayerID.length;i++) {
            if (t.LayerName[i] == theLayer){
                theLayerNumber = i
            }
        }
        if (theFormRef.checked) {
            t.LayerVisible[theLayerNumber] = 1;
            //activating layer, NB! raster layers needs to be excluded
            setActiveLayer(theLayerNumber);
        } else {
            t.LayerVisible[theLayerNumber] = 0;
        }
        t.sendMapXML();
    }
```

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=64&f=786&t=278849

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation I was able to update the active layer through the arcimsparam.js file.

Apparently, layer 3 in the TOC is index 18.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided:

> The ActiveLayerIndex starts with '0'
>   for the topmost layer and its value
>   increases in top to bottom order. So
>   for the third layer to be active,
>   insert the number 2.

So try:

```
if (ActiveLayerIndex>=layerCount) ActiveLayerIndex = 2;
```

Their [knowledge base](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/26575) says that's how it's done... call ESRI support and submit a ticket.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: @artwork, do you have an ESRI support account? If so, submit a ticket.

Comment: good idea, thx.

Comment: can you post the web link of the knowledge base statment?

Comment: @artwork, it's the same one you posted [here](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/26575).